# Why cannot typescript infer anonymous interfaces outside chained method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda, types, anonymous-types

I do not understand why Typescript is not inferring my property names in the following example.
**Example 1: Can infer type and property name**

```
//In this example TS recognizes the return type of my first map as {teamId:string,teamCode:string}[]
const foo = something.map(ele=> {
      return {
        teamId: someDict[ele.blah.id.entityId].team.id.entityId,
        teamCode: someDict[cfg.blah.id.entityId].code,
      }
    }).filter(ele => !currentTeamIds.includes(ele.teamId)).map(ele => ele.teamCode)
```

**Example 2: Cannot infer property type and name when the filter is pulled into a different statement**

```
//In this example TS marks foo as any instead of the type mentioned above.
const foo = something.map(ele=> {
      return {
        teamId: someDict[ele.blah.id.entityId].team.id.entityId,
        teamCode: someDict[cfg.blah.id.entityId].code,
      }
    })
const bar = foo.filter(ele => !currentTeamIds.includes(ele.teamId)).map(ele => ele.teamCode)
```

I thought the two examples would be equivalent. Why cannot TS infer my types when I seperate the filter out and break it from the chain ?

Comment: What is `something`? What is `someDict`?  
Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLlP4m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Something was off with my workplace settings probably. It inferred the types properly just fine after some time.